# How to use pyinstaller generate a pyqt5 sotfware?

Tags: pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to generate a executable pyqt5 software in ubuntu 16.04,but i got some trouble,how do i fix it?

My os is Ubuntu16.04LTS,and python version is anconda3 python3.6.5,
my pyqt5 is using pip to install,which show in pip list is 5.11.3,and qmake version is 3.1.
I add the anconda's lib dir into my LD_LIBRARY_PATH(if not,when i run pyinstaller myfile.py it shows "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType"),and i can successfully get my executable pyqt5 software.
BUT,when i run my executable app，something goes wrong,which is 
what should i do?Thanks a lot for your help!

> ImportError: /home/kanghao/dabao/dist/train_tool/libQt5Core.so.5:
>   version `Qt_5.11' not found (required by
>   /home/kanghao/dabao/dist/train_tool/PyQt5/QtCore.so) [11591] Failed to
>   execute script train_tool

my code is in webpage:https://blog.csdn.net/yourgreatfather/article/details/85063787

I expect my code can become a executable sotfware.

Comment: I do not think, it works with Python3.6. try do it with python 3.5.

Comment: I found that I used the wrong lib file of pyqt5,maybe because i installed several version of pyqt5,but not totoally remove them...